# Electrical circuit design questions

Tags: circuit-design

So I was wondering if there is any site or papers that has fun electrical circuit questions, such as placing the right components on a circuit to make it work, make the light dimmer/brighter by using certain components etc. I don’t want questions that involve calculations, more like placing components questions. If anyone could help that would be awesome

Comment: I don't believe there is a "place components" approach to design. A lot can be done without lots of equation work, but you'll need to learn various topologies (groups of parts organized to provide an easily understood concept or idea.) Even then there are still at least a few equations, but luckily sometimes just a few key ones to worry about more. No circuit can ignore power, voltage, etc. Of course, if you are just a builder, there are many magazines and web sites for that.

Answer (score 1):

There are software programs called circuit simulators that will let you experiment with circuits to your hearts content. Once such is called LT Spice and can be downloaded for free from the Analog/Linear web site. Once you have this tool installed you can then use the schematic editor to enter a circuit that you find someplace - or one that you devise yourself - and then use the tool to calculate everything and even show you timing diagrams of the circuit responses.

If you use your search engine you can also find a Yahoo user group for LT Spice that you can join and find lots of useful information about using the tool in more advanced ways.